# Make multiple Async Request using Angular Js Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have an array of cities with their name and url .

```
$scope.cities = [{'name':'LKO','url': 'http://sm.com'},{'name':'LK1O','url': 'http://sm1.com'}]
```

Now I need to make request to the url present in the city.. One after another as response of one request arrives.

I know this is possible using promises. 
But, I'm not able to get the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive loop like in this example:

```js
var app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("main",function($scope,$q,$http){

  
$scope.cities = [{'name':'LKO','url': 'http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39497624'},{'name':'LK1O','url': 'http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39497624'},
{'name':'LK21','url': 'http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39497624'}]
   
  //recursive function
  function getUrl(i){
      
      if (typeof $scope.cities[i]=='undefined')
      return; //last one 
      
      console.log("ajax to "+  $scope.cities[i].url);
      $http.get($scope.cities[i].url).then( getUrl(i+1) );
  };
  
  getUrl(0);//start 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
</div>
```

PS. i changed url to this github question.

Comment: much quicker to make simultaneous requests though since requests don't appear to be dependent on each other

Comment: Yes but question was different so You can not be sure that they are independent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$q.all()` to run code after an array of promises have all resolved

```
var promises = $scope.cites.map(function(city) {
  return $http.get(city.url).then(function(resp) {
    var cityData = resp.data;
    // do something with cityData here

    // then return it
    return cityData;
  });
});

$q.all(promises, function(cityDataArray) {
  // do something with array
});
```

This approach assumes that the requests are not dependent on each other and is much faster than doing it recursively

Make sure to inject `$q` into service or controller where you make these requests

Comment: Question was "One after another as response of one request arrives." This is not an answer for this.

Comment: @MaciejSikora fine but i'm not sure that isn't an X-Y problem in question

Comment: the title said "multiple"... for multiple, it's used $q.all()... probably a better title is "sequential" or similar word.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are complicated. Here is a simpler one:

```
const cities = [{'name':'LKO','url': 'http://sm.com'}, ...]
const queue = $q.resolve(); // get an empty promise
for(const city of cities) { // angular.forEach if you want to avoid for...of
   queue = queue.then(() => $http.get(city.url).then(/* write result to scope*/))
}
```

You just chain the promises in a loop.